# Cannot connect to Mysql database with HostGator (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, connection

I've been trying to connect to my MYSQL database on my newly acquired website through a PDO connection which is quoted below, and it doesn't seem to be working properly, as it fails as soon as I try using a query or to add an entry. All the information seems to be right, but whenever I try using any command, as selecting or adding entries, it gives me this error:

> Array ( [0] => 3D000 [1] => 1046 [2] => No database selected ) 1

Here are the lines of my connection:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:localhost;dbname=username_dbName', 'username_dbUser', 'password');
}
catch (Exception $e) {
        die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
        print 'Unable to Connect. Please contact the website administrator.';
}
```

And here is the code I used to test if queries worked.

```
$req = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO testTable(number) 
                        VALUES(:number)');
$req->execute(array('number' => 13)) or die(print_r($req->errorInfo()));
```

Obviously I use the actual login values for the connection, but it's not working and I can't figure why.
My website is hosted by HostGator, if that can help.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=username_dbName;host=localhost', 'username_dbUser', 'password');
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! This worked right away! How didn't I realize I was missing the "host=" ...

Answer (score 1):

I think a problem is with `localhost` you indicate. Some hosting services require you to use something other than `localhost`. You might perhaps try `127.0.0.1` instead of it.

If it does not help and you are sure your username, password, and database parameters are all the way correct, I believe you will need to ask your hosting provider for a correct mysql server address.

Answer (score 0):

in your real code is `username_dbName` a variable, like `$username_dbName` ? In that case you should use double quotes instead of single quotes.

```
"mysql:localhost;dbname=$username_dbName"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'username_dbName';
$username = 'username_dbUser';
$pw = 'password';
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $pw);
```

EDIT: corrected typo

Comment: Thanks alot! Marie_d and you made me realize I was missing the host= eheh.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  'driver'    => 'mysql',
  'host'      => '(use the server IP address)',
  'database'  => '(database Name)',
  'username'  => '(database Username)',
  'password'  => '(the password you entered for that database user)',
  'charset'   => 'utf8',
  'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
  'prefix'    => ''
```